# preventDefault() cant work on('submit') function

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-submit, preventdefault

I have this code:

```
<form action="/example/call/to/api" id="myId" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
```

And on external .js file i've done this function:

```
$('#myId').on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $.post("URL"+$(this).attr('action'), function(c) {
      var objJson = $.parseJSON(c);
      var url = objJson[0].url;
      $.ajax({
        ('#myId').on('submit',(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url: url,
             data:formData,
             cache:false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             xhr: function () {
             //some code here,      
             success:function(html){
             //some code here
```

The problem is that i need no redirection, but now when, submit the form, i've been always redirected on /example/call/to/api  :/  Why in this case preventDefault can't work?

**The call works, the problem is that "preventDefault" is not working!**

**SOLVED**, I just had the same function that was pointed to the same ID to make different request (by action inside each form).
Just divided the functions for each action and all works!
**The function just take the 1st ID inside the code and ignore all the others.**

Comment: Is your submit handler being called at all?

Comment: 1. Check to see if you script is indeed added to your html, 2. Ensure it's wrapped in a document.ready function, 3. Check your console for errors

Comment: Sorry, code updated! Script is inside html, start when document is ready, console give no errors.

Comment: Your code works for me. Problem must be elsewhere in the code. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: ` $.ajax({
        ('#myId').on('submit',(function(e) {
` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the $ or jQuery before the `('#myId')` and you have an extra `(` before your submit handler function.

```
$('#myId').on('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 url: url,
 data:formData,
 cache:false,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 xhr: function () {
 //some code here
 },      
 success:function(html){
 //some code here 
 }
 });
```

You will also need to make sure you are running your code when the document is ready; otherwise, your form will not exist yet.

```
$(function(){
  $('#myId').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 url: url,
 data:formData,
 cache:false,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 xhr: function () {
 //some code here
 },      
 success:function(html){
 //some code here 
 }
 });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your on click event have to look like as this one

```
('#myId').on('submit', function() {...}
```

not `('#myId').on('submit', (function() {...})`

just remove `(` on the start and end of the function

Comment: Why is that? I don't see why that prevents `preventDefault()` from being executed. It's not needed to use `( ... )`, I agree with that, but it's not a fault right?